# Nested view through a linked server gives select permission denied

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I have come across a funny permissions issue with nested views that I don't think is caused by ownership chaining.  All servers mentioned are SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a linked server that is configured to use a specific login, say, Bill.  On my remote server I have a view, let's call it `ViewA`, which in turn selects from another view, let's call it `ViewB`.

I can do a select through the linked server which works just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[VIEWA]
```

This returns a happy result set, no problem.

Now, I have a stored procedure which is attempting to query from the same view.  It is using the same linked server, remember, which is using the same login, Bill.

When I `EXECUTE` the stored procedure through management studio, which in turn queries `ViewA` through the linked server, I get:

> *SELECT permission denied on ViewB.*

The login that the linked server is using, Bill, is part of a role which has explicit access to `View A`. Both views are part of the same schema, and all objects are owned by dbo.

Notice it is not complaining about `ViewA`, which Bill has explicit rights to, but `ViewB`, which Bill should have rights to because of ownership chaining.

I don't understand why I can query through the Bill Linked Server directly, but the stored procedure fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you call SP with from SQL Server management studio or from application.

Comment: through management studio.  Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The role has permissions to select from `[ViewA]`, but you haven't so far confirmed the permissions on the stored procedure. You will most probably need to run something similar to the following:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [InsertProcedureNameHere] TO [InsertRoleNameHere];
```

More information on the GRANT statement may be found here:
[GRANT object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx)